# Firebase data received on simulator ok, but is not received on some iOS real devices

Tags: ios, firebase

We are seeing a really weird issue on iOS with Firebase. Some users iPhones are receiving data/sending data to Firebase fine. Our testing on sims is fine.

However some users, are not able to receive or send any data with Firebase. We confirmed that the listeners are triggered and 'waiting' on those devices but no data is being received.

Has anyone had this same issue and resolved it?

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it seems unlikely that anyone will be able to answer.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting back on this, the question was initially just to see if others had come across the same scenario, before we posted any code etc.

Anyway the long and short of it after much testing and debugging is that these problems we're NOT related to Firebase's own APIs but rather the Firestack lib which is a React Native bridge. Should have made that (Firestack) clearer in original post. We have thrown out the Firestack lib completely and are using Firebase's own JS APIs - and this particular strange issue, is gone (fixed) with no adjustment to our code necessary other than swapping out the API calls.